# Parsing only a part of HTML data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse a website using the following code. I am able to parse the website and print data, current output is @http://pastie.org/6448357 ,however, I only want to print only a part of the data in the link,expected output is @http://pastie.org/6448362 Can anyone provide inputs on how can this be done?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import argparse
import urllib
import urllib2
import getpass
import re
import requests

def update (url):
    print url
    req = urllib2.Request(url=url)
    try:
        f = urllib2.urlopen(req)
        txt = f.read()
        soup = bs(txt)
        print soup
        f.close()


def main ():
    #For logging
    print "test"
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the update.py script created by test')
    parser.add_argument('-u','--url',action='store',dest='url',default=None,help='<Required> url link',required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args()# collect cmd line args
    url = results.url
    #print url
    update(url)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do not use an external resource like pastie for providing additonal information. Everything belongs into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[i am not able to comment I dont know why.. :P]

I havent used beautifulsoup but generally when I have to retrieve some section from an entire web page i just look for unique identifiers surrounding the important data..

for example in your case `{|` and `|}` occur uniquely.

So simply read the entire page and find your data:

```
site=urllib2.urlopen(url1) 
a=site.read()
c1=a.find('{|')
c2=a.find('|}')
c=c1
while(c<c2):
    print a[c]
    c+=1
```

Comment: Thanks,there are so many blocks that has {| and  |}..I only want to block after the line "==== &lt;font color="#008000"&gt;Data/text Build Combo&lt;/font&gt; ====" how can this be done?

Comment: also..its printing each letter in a new line

Comment: well in that case use the unique start identifier in `a.find` like the one you mentioned.. the `find` statement looks for the first occurrence of a string from the current position. So the end identifier can very well be `|}`

What you can do is that instead of `print a[c]`you write `b+=a[c]`; this will store that region in `b`. you can manipulate `b` later if you want.